# Change attribute output from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any way to change the output of an attribute from inside the model?

For example, if I have an attribute called `bar` in a `Foo` class, I would like it to be displayed *titleized*.

I tried by defining it inside the model:

```
def bar
  self.bar.titleize
end
```

But got an `stack level too deep` error, because it was redefining itself recursively.

Perhaps the most logical way would be to handle it when I save the record, which I will finally maybe do. But I was wondering if it would be possible something like this.

Comment: Why don't you use `super`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to overriden `bar` method with `super`:

```
def bar
  super.titleize
end
```